# warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to deploy a simple **JSF** application in **netbeans**, but it shows me the error:

> Compiling 10 source files to C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RealEstate\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
> Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
> Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
> Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
> Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
> Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
> Note: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RealEstate\src\java\Session\AbstractFacade.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

When I run the application the error is:

> C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RealEstate\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
> See the server log for details.

I tried all the solutions I found here but none of them worked. Can you please help me?

Comment: This is a pure jpa thing and maybe eclipselink. Nothing JSF related.

Comment: Can you help me with more information where to look up for the problem?

Comment: Sure, read the last sentence of what you quoted and act on it... Check the server logs... But there it ends... I don't use eclipslink nor netbeans

Comment: I found online that this was a bug of jdk. In addition must be added : https://git.eclipse.org/c/eclipselink/eclipselink.runtime.git/tree/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/modelgen/CanonicalModelProcessor.java?id=ad5fbbdfc33cd17cd99479dc89756ec4ef7ee6a7                                       But still it shows me error, can sb help me?